# Is there such a thing as Kaddish Talmidim?

Tags: kaddish

Has anyone heard of a Kaddish said for teachers and students? I have heard it called "Kaddish Talmidim" but find nothing online at all.

Comment: The general format is to answer here on the site. If you want you can sign up for e-mail updates regarding your question.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're thinking of Kaddish d'Rabbanan, whose text includes:

> עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל וְעַל רַבָּנָן. וְעַל תַּלְמִידֵיהוֹן וְעַל כָּל תַּלְמִידֵי תַלְמִידֵיהוֹן. וְעַל כָּל מַאן דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא. דִּי בְאַתְרָא קַדִּישָׁא הָדֵין וְדִי בְכָל אֲתַר וַאֲתַר
>
> For Yisrael, and the Rebbeim, and their talmidim, and the talmidim of those talmidim, and for all who toils in Torah, whether in this place or in any other place... [may they have various blessings, and say Amen].